# Why can't I chmod to make a file executable without sudo?

Tags: permission, unix, path, sudo

On OS X 10.6.8, I made a small script file in my home directory and tried to make it executable. Surprisingly, I found that `chmod` had no effect until I ran it as super-user. I own and have write access to my home directory directory and the script, so what prevents chmod from working?

```
my_mac:~ crowding$ ls -dle ~
drwxr-xr-x+ 214 crowding  staff  7276 Jul 28 16:30 /Users/crowding
 0: group:everyone deny delete
my_mac:~ crowding$ ls -le ~/my_script 
-rw-r--r--  1 crowding  staff  22 Jul 28 16:25 /Users/crowding/my_script
my_mac:~ crowding$ chmod a+x ~/my_script 
my_mac:~ crowding$ ls -le ~/my_script 
-rw-r--r--  1 crowding  staff  22 Jul 28 16:25 /Users/crowding/my_script
my_mac:~ crowding$ sudo chmod a+x ~/my_script 
Password:
my_mac:~ crowding$ ls -le ~/my_script 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 crowding  staff  22 Jul 28 16:25 /Users/crowding/my_script
my_mac:~ crowding$
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. Did you configure ACL?

Comment: The problem seems to be confined to one account on this machine. The ACLs appear normal. and it seems to happen anywhere I try in the file system. It seems to be related to something in my PATH, but not the chmod binary itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was another exec "chmod" on the path, obscuring my own chmod.

The thing that made this difficult to see was that I'd used the metacharacter "~" in my PATH variable. Only some things will interpret a tilde in the PATH. The `which` program does not expand the tilde, so `which chmod` told me that `/bin/chmod` was the chmod on the path, but bash *does* expand the tilde, so it tried to run the other chmod (which did nothing.) Meanwhile, `sudo` does *not* expand the tilde so it worked, and gave the impression of a permissions problem.

Resolution: when adding subdirectories of your home directory to your `PATH,` use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Comment: How did you set you PATH variable then? Any ~ in it should get expanded (replaced by `/Users/crowding`) automatically by the shell when getting assigned to a variable.

Comment: ~ doesn't get expanded in double quoted strings.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if other things break as well if you have `~` in $PATH. That's why I always recommend to avoid using quotes when assigning something to $PATH.